# Define a field as a parameter in a Query

Tags: ms-access

I have a field in a table(1) that can be filled with two different fields from another table(2). Both of the tables are linked through their Primary Key. How do I create a Update Query that uses a parameter to define which field will be used at the update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example, tblSource has 2 date fields, date1 and date2.  The parameter WhichDate is used with the Switch() function to determine which of those 2 fields is used to update date_assigned in tblTarget.

```
PARAMETERS WhichDate Long;
UPDATE tblTarget AS t INNER JOIN tblSource AS s ON t.id = s.id
SET t.date_assigned = Switch(WhichDate=1,date1,WhichDate=2,date2);
```

Comment: This works in MS Access?!! I will be a surprised and happy camper. Maybe they added this in the 2010 version? I am going to go check this out right now . ..

Comment: @XIVSolutions I tested with Access 2003.

Comment: I'm not a fan of Switch() or Choose(), as both tend to get you into storing data in your SQL statements -- data belongs in tables, not in the SQL.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you get to do this directly in MS Access. You could mimic this behavior if you are using VBA code, but my best (possibly incomplete) understanding is that you won't be able to use a Parameter to reference a Database object.

With VBA (or any other client code) you could set up a method which accepts a method parameter that establishes which column to update, and then assemble the appropriate SQL statement from there.